# Finding the volume of revolution using the method of shells

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm trying to find the volume of the solid  generated by revolving  the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=6x+7$ about $x$-axis using the shell method. I applied the method and I got $15864/5$ multiplied by $\pi$   but it's not correct.

Details: I integrated $$\int_{1}^{49}y(\sqrt{y}-\frac{y-7}{6})dy$$

Comment: Please add *how* you applied the method. What bounds for $x$ did you integrate over? How did you set up your integral? It's hard to help you figure out where you may have gone wrong unless you include such information.

Comment: I  integrated ((sqrty)-(y-7)/6)(y) , y from 1 to 49

Comment: I don't know if it's required to use shell method; but I think this problem would be easier to do with washers (with integration with respect to $x$, the region has the same boundary curves throughout the region of integration; not so with an integral with respect to $y$).

Answer (score 0):

For revolving about the $x$-axis, use washers.  Then $V=\pi\int_{-1}^7 [(6x+7)^2-(x^2)^2]dx$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the shell method, then you would need

$\displaystyle\int_0^{1}2\pi y\left(\sqrt{y}-(-\sqrt{y})\right) dy +\int_{1}^{49}2\pi y\left(\sqrt{y}-\frac{y-7}{6}\right) dy$;

but using the disc method as indicated in the other answer is easier.